# авторизация приожения в яндекс деньгах

Tags: python, flask, yandex-money

использую python 3.6 и flask . обертка для яндекса sdk-https://github.com/yandex-money/yandex-money-sdk-python.

```
from yandex_money.api import Wallet, ExternalPayment
from yandex_money import api
import requests
from flask import request
import requests
from flask import Flask, session, redirect, url_for, escape
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
#token = api.Wallet.get_access_token(client_id='...',code=requests.get['code'],redirect_uri='http//ddd.pythonanywhere.com')
client_id='...'
ym_account='@yandex.ru'
credit=10
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def ymon():
    scope = ['account-info', 'operation-history']
    redirect_uri='https://www.http://weblabla.pythonanywhere.com/'
    client_id'...'
    auth_url = Wallet.build_obtain_token_url(client_secret, redirect_uri,scope,) + '&response_type=code'

    return redirect(auth_url)


@app.route('/ya', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def ymon1():

    code = requests.GET['code']
    access_token = Wallet.get_access_token(client_id, code, redirect_uri)
    access_token = access_token['access_token']
    wallet = Wallet(access_token)

request_options = {
    "pattern_id": "p2p",
    "to": "%s" % ym_account,
    "amount": "%s" % credit,
    "comment": "comment",
    "message": "message",
    "label": "testPayment",
}

request_result = wallet.request_payment(options=request_options)
....
process_payment = wallet.process_payment({"request_id": request_result['request_id'],})
```

получаю при попытке авторизации-
Ошибка
Этому приложению отказано в доступе.
Свяжитесь с его разработчиком и укажите сведения об ошибке (invalid_request)

не могу авторизоваться и получить код .Подскажите ,что не так

Comment: 1. У `client_id='...'` значение в реальном скрипте есть? 2. `redirect_uri` выглядит странно

Comment: все есть , просто тут ,что бы выложить немного изменил